# Changing a link to :active state when a keyboard button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

How do I change the status of a link to its `:active` state when I press a button?

Example: When I press the up key, a specific link changes to its `<code>:active</code>` state.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've previously used the KeyCheck function to associate links with keys on the keyboard, but in this case, I'm trying to just change the link's status to active.

Comment: Hmm.. Please post the code you're working on, I suppose there is nobody here in SO, who wants to do all the job for free.

Comment: Well, I don't have the code for this but this is the code that I was using when I was reverting to Keycheck:


`<script type="text/javascript">  
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;  
   function KeyCheck(e)  
 {  
     var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;  
            switch(KeyID)  
  {  
         case 30:  
        window.location = "Test.html";  
        break;  
   
        case 31:  
        window.location = "Test2.html";  
        break;  
     }  
 }  
</script>`

Comment: Why would you need to programmatically switch a link into the `:active` state? Why don't you just style it by applying a class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to change the look of the link, and not the actual link state. That's fairly straight-forward to accomplish, by watching for the keyup event, and adding the same visual style as "active links" to your link.

```
$('body').live('keyup',function(e){
     if(e.which == 38)
     {
          $('#mylink').addClass("activeLinkClass");             
     }
});
```

If you actually want to change the state (possibly because you're using the link state as part of the program logic), It's my understanding that that's managed by the browser; you'd need to clear the entry from the browsing history, which I don't believe is possible with javascript.

note: this code works for me in a quick test on chrome, but hasn't really been tested